# Rails: how to use options correctly for bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, config

I'm just tried to create a new rails app on a server running rails 3.2.5 (ruby 1.8.7), using a mysql backend:

```
rails new myapp -d mysql
```

So far everything went well. However if I try to create the database with `rake db:create` I get this:

```
Could not find gem 'therubyracer (~> 0.12.0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

If I do as recommended (run `bundle install`) I get a list of gems which are going to be used (and seem to installed already) aand at the another error occurs:

```
...
Using ref (1.0.5) 
Using sass (3.2.13) 
Using sass-rails (3.2.6) 
Installing therubyracer (0.12.0) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby18 extconf.rb 
checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
checking for v8.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

So to me this suggests that rake is looking for v8 in the wrong location. The error posting also makes a suggestion on how to solve this using configuration options:

```
You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/usr/bin/ruby18
--with-pthreadlib
--without-pthreadlib
--enable-debug
--disable-debug
--with-v8-dir
--without-v8-dir
--with-v8-include
--without-v8-include=${v8-dir}/include
--with-v8-lib
--without-v8-lib=${v8-dir}/lib
/kunden/378731_1150/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:50:in `configure': You have chosen to use the version of V8 found on your system (Libv8::Location::System::NotFoundError) and *not* the one that is bundle with the libv8 rubygem. However, it could not be located. please make sure you have a version of v8 that is compatible with 3.16.14.3 installed. You may need to special --with-v8-dir options if it is in a non-standard location
```

It looks like I have to configure the `bundle` process like `bundle config --some-option` but which option would do the trick? I've tried all those v8 related options but none of them worked. The option beginning with `--with-v8-xxx` don't seem to allow setting a path to the locally installed v8 lib (`gem list` gives me `Using libv8 (3.16.14.3)` and I can see the folder in my local `.gem` directory). The `--without-v8-xxx` aren't usable either as I don't know the location of the system-wide v8 lib (don't have the permissions to search the server).

How can I solve my problem?

Thanks

---

Ok, looks like I've been able to proceed a bit. Invoking installation like `RUBYOPT=-rrubygems gem install libv8` *seems* to have convinced extconf.rb to look for v8.h in my local gems rather than in a system location. However, I'm not there yet:

```
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby18 extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

... and later:

```
/kunden/378731_1150/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:15:in `initialize': No such file or directory - /kunden/378731_1150/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/.location.yml (Errno::ENOENT)
from /kunden/378731_1150/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:15:in `open'
from /kunden/378731_1150/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:15:in `load!'
from /kunden/378731_1150/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/lib/libv8.rb:6:in `configure_makefile'
from extconf.rb:32
```

The error posting also offers me a couple of option I could use but I don't at all understand what *causes* the error.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use `bundle config` to pass the configuration flags to your gems, like this

```
bundle config build.libv8 --without-v8-lib=/path/to/lib
```

Check bundle config man page for more info by running `bundle help config`

**UPDATE**: Judging by the error message you got, it seems that the libv8 gem was being built while looking for the *system's v8* (not sure why this was the default). Luckily, the gem is bundled with v8 source, but you need to explicitly tell it to use it, like this

```
bundle config build.libv8 --without-system-v8
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. Now I see I got a .bundle directory in my home dir, containing the configuration that I've set just before. However, things still don't work - I _don't know_ the **without** path (unfortunately). Simply changing --without-v8-lib to --with-v8-lib and providing the path to my locally installed gem doesn't work (I think --with-v8-lib doesn't take any path...)

Comment: I'm sorry to say - bundle config build.libv8 --without-system-v8 didn't do the trick either. Still bundle install is looking for v8.h in the wrong location:

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby18 extconf.rb 
checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
checking for v8.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***

Comment: You sure that's not because of a conflict between the flags you set before (--with-v8-lib) and the system-v8 flag?

Comment: I guess so... as far as I can see all set the --without-system-v8 option did was rewrite ~/.bundle/config to BUNDLE_BUILD__LIBV8: --without-system-v8

Comment: I'm afraid I have nothing more to help you with, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
gem install libv8 -v 3.11.8.17 -- --with-system-v8
```